# Importing an excerpt from a file into a script

Tags: bash, files, text-processing

I'm trying to import an excerpt from a file into a script for processing.

```
LIST=$(sed '1,/+++NETWORKLIST+++/d' < /path/to/file | sort -t ";" -k2,2r)
```

My problem is that this script is not deleting the material I don't want to pass on - I want to delete all the lines up to and including NETWORKLIST. (Beyond that point is entirely a list, with fields separted by semicolons, which I want to pass on to be sorted.)

How do I pass on just an experpt from a file?

Comment: how is the file arranged?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @operalala Hi. Are you trying to "process" the section of text or are you trying to delete it? Please provide more information about the file contents.

Comment: I want to delete the section that I don't want to process, because it will mess up the processing. Then I want to process what is left. At least that's the idea I was going for. I'm open to other ways to import a file section, tho :)

Comment: @operalala. We need more info about the file. Are there two sections, and by deleting everything up to "NETWORKLIST" you will end up with just the section you need? If possible, delete any sensible information from the file and upload it to your question.

Comment: Yes, just delete everything up to NETWORKLIST.

Comment: If you don't show us the file, we have no idea what you're talking about. What's a "section"? How is it defined? Is a section a single line? Many lines? Delimited by consecutive newlines?  By section headers?Please show your input and desired output.

Comment: aha - Ok, I replaced "section" with "excerpt" in the post

Comment: What I want to delete are all the lines up to and including NETWORKLIST. Beyond that point is entirely a list, with fields separted by semicolons.

Comment: I tried to reproduce with the information you provided and it works for me. I get in the `LIST` variable only the stuff after `+++NETWORKLIST+++`

Comment: Thank you - that is strange, the problem must be within my file - the file is a bash script, so I tried removing the `#!/bin/bash` and the `exit` at the end, and it still wouldn't work.

Comment: How does one post 150 lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following file:

```
testline1
testline2
NETWORKLIST
line with spaces, just in case
and with    tabs
+++NETWORKLIST+++
thisisrelevant
thistoo

+++ANOTHERSECTION+++
someirrelevanttext
```

And you want to extract only the NETWORKLIST section like this:

```
+++NETWORKLIST+++
thisisrelevant
thistoo
```

Then your sed mojo to do it is:

```
sed -n '/+++NETWORKLIST+++/,/^+/ { x; /^$/! p; }' testfile
```

---

### Disection of a sed command

This is an address range pattern:

```
/+++NETWORKLIST+++/,/^+/
```

It will match all the lines starting at `+++NETWORKLIST+++` and ending at a line starting with `+`.

Then comes the commands:

The `{` opens a command list (it's not usually seen as most users of sed actually use a single command after matching).

The `x;` exchanges the contents of the hold space and the pattern space (see [The Concept of 'Hold space' and 'Pattern space' in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833714/the-concept-of-hold-space-and-pattern-space-in-sed)).

Then, we want to print nonempty lines: `/^$/! p;`

Also, close command list: `}`

Why do this exchange? Well, after matching the range, we're left with this input:

```
+++NETWORKLIST+++
thisisrelevant
thistoo

+++ANOTHERSECTION+++
```

But we are not interested in the section header for the next section.

Thus, we tell sed to put each line on the hold space.

If the file had a section closer such as `---NETWORKLIST---` we would simply do:

```
sed -n '/+++NETWORKLIST+++/,/^-/ p'
```

Or even this if we don't want the section finalizer:

```
sed -n '/+++NETWORKLIST+++/,/^-/ {/^-/d; p}'
```

But if we try that for OP's input, we would loose the section header from the relevant section.

By doing the `x` on each step, we are effectively skipping the last line of the range:

1. PatternSpace=`+++NETWORKLIST+++`, HoldSpace=`^$`. Exchange them
2. PatternSpace=`thisisrelevant`, HoldSpace=`+++NETWORKLIST+++`. Exchange them, print PatternSpace
3. PatternSpace=`thistoo`, HoldSpace=`thisisrelevant`. Exchange them, print PatternSpace
4. PatternSpace=`^$`, HoldSpace=`thistoo`. Exchange them, print PatternSpace
5. PatternSpace=`+++ANOTHERSECTION+++`, HoldSpace=`^$`. Exchange them.
6. There's no more input

Please leave a comment if it's unclear or I used the wrong name for a sed concept.

Comment: could you please explain your sed line.

Comment: @bersch: there you go

Comment: The problem does not appear to be the `sed` command, but something with the file that is not working, or is choking `sed`, or something. The file is 150 lines, and I don't know how to post it.